Are constructive proofs harder than non-constructive proofs?
In both linear algebra and real analysis, it has persistently been my experience that it is more difficult and time consuming to do a constructive proof of a proposition than a non-constructive proof. I had always taken that for granted as some quirk of mine, but recently I wondered: is this really just a quirk of mine or might this pattern be indicative of some property of the logical structure of constructive and non-constructive proofs that makes the former intrinsically harder?
I know the answer might simply be that this is just a me thing, in which case this is perhaps not the best website for this question. But it has happened to me enough that I thought I would inquire into others experiences with it and if it’s a “real” thing.

This is a prototype of an opinion-based question. Hence I vote to close.

@MartinBrandenburg really? OP is asking for an actual mathematical reason for the difficult of constructive proofs, which can be measured in terms of proof length and complexity. Everyone on this site loves to close questions out of spite it seems.That’s an opinion.

@PW_246: That may be what the OP means, but it is not at all clear to me. There are other formal meanings of "constructive" than what you say, but it's not even clear that the OP has in mind any formal meaning of "constructive" at all. Perhaps the intention is just some opinion-based critique of proofs as suggested in the other comment. The OP should probably clear this up.

Constructive mathematics

Depends. Sometimes thyey are harder. I since constructive mathematics is a subset of math with non-constructive techniques, so if there is a constructive proof, there is always the same proof in non-constructive math, but there might not be an easier proof using those non+-constructive techniques. Sometimes there will be, though - say, an easier proof by contradiction

In particular, if you can prove something constructively, you can, with virtually no added complexity, make it non-constructive, by assume $\lnot P,$ then proving $P$, you've reached a contradiction! So $P$ is true. So it is unclear even what is meant by a "non-constructive proof." Proof by contradiction is non-constructive, but this is logically just a fig leaf, so it is unclear if you would call this a non-constructive proof., or how you would formally define "non-constructive proof." Since non-constructive math is constructive math with a few tools added, it can only have = proofs,

Yes, constructive mathematics is an entire field of its own, and proving basic results about e.g. the real numbers often requires much more care and subtlety than in the classical world. Classical proofs are easier than constructive proofs in the precise sense that every constructive proof is a classical proof; staying constructive requires effort. (Remember that a constructive proof is simply one that does not use any classical principles like excluded middle or choice.)
